# Python call functions from a list in a certain order

Tags: python, function

I have the following example:

```
def func1():return 1
def func2():return 2
def func3():return 3

fl = [func1,func2,func3]
```

I want to call the functions in a certain order; for example

- func1(), then func2(), lastly func3()

or

- func2(), then func1(), lastly func3()

How can that happen?

Comment: What dictates the order?

Comment: Simply loop through the list, calling each function: `[f() for f in fl()]`

Comment: `[fl[i]() for i in order]` where `order=[2,1,3]` etc

Comment: @Aran-Fey, its about the chronology of function call, first func1()....lastly func3() or any selected order

Comment: Ok I got it, I parsed that sentence incorrectly. But more importantly, you need to clarify what order you want to call those functions in. And what's the purpose of that `f1` list?

Comment: @Grant, am getting: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @loved_by_Jesus my bad, 0 indexed, `order=[1,0,2]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specify the indices you want, and iterate over it. Note that list indices in Python are zero-indexed.

```
def func1():return 1
def func2():return 2
def func3():return 3

fl = [func1,func2,func3]
indices = [0,1,2,1,0,2]
for i in indices:
    fl[i]()
```

Comment: I hit enter by accident, that is exactly the approach I was going to suggest

Comment: @RafaelC, I updated the answer. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: What's the point of having a list of functions *and* a list of indices? One of those is redundant.

Comment: Ok then he can do: `[eval('func{}()'.format(i)) for i in indices]`

Comment: @Aran-Fey, I am answering the question using my best interpretation of the OP's intent, namely that he has a fixed list of functions and wants to iterate over them.

Comment: @GrantMcCloskey, Perhaps the functions aren't actually named quite so facetiously in his real code? :P

Comment: @merlin2011 let me dream

Answer (score 0):

Don't put functions in a list. Use a python *program* instead

```
func1()
func2()
func3()
```

If you really want tom just loop though the list

```
for f in [func1, func2, func3]:
    f()
```

Comment: "Don't put functions in a list" <- why not?

Comment: Which of the above two examples do you feel is easiest to read?

Comment: Which of the two examples calls functions in an arbitrary order?

Comment: am importing from another module as a list, that's why

Comment: either method lets you call the function in arbitrary order. Especially the second version is very flexible as you can use any list here, e.g. `[func3, func2, func3, func1]` or whatever.

Comment: Your first method doesn't. You've hard-coded the order. The script runs top to bottom and the order is fixed. If they're in a list or a dictionary, the functions can be executed as many times as you like, in whatever order, based on some dynamic input. I think the instruction not to put functions in some container is not correct.

Comment: Or, to clarify, there can be good reasons to put functions in a list. I'm not arguing it's the best way for all cases, but it shouldn't be ruled out in a general case.